# Getting compile errors when compiling gnu cgi for web project

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, g++, gnu

On my raspberry pi I am using c++ to write a web project.  I am following [C++ CGI](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm). I installed gnu's cgi library using `apt-get installed libcgicc3`.  When I compile the form `g++ -o cform.cgi cform.cpp` i am getting the following error. `Fatal error cgicc/CgiDefs.h no such file`. How do I find the cgi library.  I have seen an example of the compile `g++ -o file.cgi file.cpp /usr/libcgicc.a` that doesn't work for me.  `libcgicc.a` is not in that directory.  Where can I find the file to compile the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to install the [libcgicc-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libcgicc-dev) package instead, that containers header files and the library to link to.

To link with the library (called libcgicc.so):

```
g++ -o file.cgi file.cpp -lcgicc
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Getting other errors that has to do with code, but compiling works.  Where did you find installing `libcgicc-dev` was needed.

Comment: This is a convention in Debian packages. Go to packages.debian.org and try searching for the missing header file (under package contents)